# How can I improve the performance of this nested loop?

Tags: python, oop

I'm working on a matching problem where I have to assign students to schools. The issue is that I have to consider siblings for each student since is a relevant feature at the time of setting priorities for each school.

My data looks like the one below.

```
Index Student_ID    Brothers
0   92713846    [79732346]
1   69095898    [83462239]
2   67668672    [75788479, 56655021, 75869616]
3   83396441    []
4   65657616    [52821691]
5   62399116    []
6   78570850    [62046889, 63029349]
7   69185379    [70285250, 78819847, 78330994]
8   66874272    []
9   78624173    [73902609, 99802441, 95706649]
10  97134369    []
11  77358607    [52492909, 59830215, 71251829]
12  56314554    [54345813, 71451741]
13  97724180    [64626337]
14  73480196    [84454182, 90435785]
15  70717221    [60965551, 98620966, 70969443]
16  60942420    [54370313, 63581164, 72976764]
17  81882157    [78787923]
18  73387623    [87909970, 57105395]
19  59115621    [62494654]
20  54650043    [69308874, 88206688]
21  53368352    [63191962, 53031183]
22  76024585    [61392497]
23  84337377    [58419239, 96762668]
24  50099636    [80373936, 54314342]
25  62184397    [89185875, 84892080, 53223034]
26  85704767    [85509773, 81710287, 78387716]
27  85585603    [66254198, 87569015, 52455599]
28  82964119    [76360309, 76069982]
29  53776152    [92585971, 74907523]
...
6204 rows × 2 columns
```

`Student_ID` is a unique id for each student, and `Brothers` is a list with all the ids that are siblings of that student.

In order to save my data for the matching, I create a Student class, where I save all the attributes that I need for the matching. Here is a [link to download the entire dataset](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rgg9sgcsqsmhjcl/example.csv?dl=1).

```py
class Student():
    def __init__(self, index, id, vbrothers = []):
        self.__index = index
        self.__id = id
        self.__vbrothers = vbrothers

    @property
    def index(self):
        return self.__index

    @property
    def id(self):
        return self.__id

    @property
    def vbrothers(self):
        return self.__vbrothers
```

I'm instantiating my Student class object doing a loop on all the rows of my dataframe, an then appending each one in a list:

```py
students = []
for index, row in students_data.iterrows():
    student = Student(index, row['Student_ID'],  row['Brothers'])
    students.append(student)
```

Now, my problem is that I need a pointer to the index of each sibling in the `students` list. Actually, I'm implementing this nested loop:

```py
for student in students:
    student.vbrothers_index = [brother.index for brother in students if (student.id in brother.vbrothers)]
```

This is by far the section with the worst performance of my entire code. It's 4 times slower than the second-worst section.

Any suggestion on how to improve the performance of this nested loop is welcome.

Comment: Does the order of entries in `students` matter?

Comment: It doesn't matter. Since I have the id to identify the student and siblings, the order is of no relevance at that point.

Comment: Then make it a dictionary.  The list comprehension causes the loop to have quadratic complexity.

Comment: I think i got it, but can you give me an example to be sure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since order in `students` does not matter, make it a dictionary:

```
students = {}
for index, row in students_data.iterrows():
    student = Student(index, row['Student_ID'],  row['Brothers'])
    students[row['Student_ID']] = student
```

Now, you can retrieve each student by his ID in constant time:

```
for student in students:
    student.vbrothers_index = [students[brother.id].index for brother in student.vbrothers]
```

Comment: I change the entire logic of the code to use dictionaries instead of lists and the codes improve a lot!!! Thanks